# Application get crash in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I don't understand why my app crashed, what was the problem ?
It shows me in console after getting crash:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/HarishYadav/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/4E533D74-819B-4E6B-9237-D900D3420122/Journey.app> (loaded)' with name 'uMainWindow''
*** Call stack at first throw:
```

I really don't know what mistake I make. Even I didn't do any thing. I just opened the XIB for checking but I didn't do anything in that. What was the problem and how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception says you're trying to load a XIB called `uMainWindow.xib` (on the iPhone it'll actually be named `uMainWindow.nib` but iOS knows that), but there is no such XIB in your bundle. You need to make sure it actually exists and is part of your project.

Another common problem seems to be wrong file type: Select the file in the project navigator (the Finder-like thing on the left), then in the menu select *"View -> Utilities -> File Inspector"*. Now on the right, there's a drop-down box called *"File Type"*. Make sure it is set to *"Interface Builder XIB"*.

Comment: i get the View -> Utilities -> File Inspector". Now on the right, there's a drop-down box called "File Type". Make sure it is set to "Interface Builder XIB". can explain me more

Comment: when put breck point on main class it get crash after this line int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);

Comment: @Shima: You just click on the drop-down box. A kind of menu will appear. There you need to click on the entry *"Interface Builder XIB"*.

Comment: is that that i have select the mainwindow.xib file than i find the drop-down box or something else .

Comment: Wait a minute: please post the *exact* filename of your XIB: is it *"uMainWindow.xib"*, as your exceptions says, or is it *"MainWindow.xib"* ? If it is the later, you have somewhere entered *"uMainWindow" by mistake.

Comment: i doesn't make any change in MainWindow.xib when i put break point on it  int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil); it get crash with Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/HarishYadav/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/A6DC7F9F-F271-4DA8-B937-B05CA42EDA84/Journey.app> (loaded)' with name 'uMainWindow'' *** Call stack at first throw I think may be it has threading problem then how program the main.m file

Comment: My program flow is like that (1)agreement page it was come only once in life of program >(2)login UIALert page which has the two button >(3)actual login page than after i use all tabbar class for different page I didn't use the MainWindow.xib

Comment: You haven't answered my question, but I assume that your file is in fact named *"MainWindow.xib"*. You somewhere entered *"uMainWindow"* instead. In your Xcode menu, select *View -> Navigators -> Project*. In the list on the left (your project files) select the project which is top-most item with a blue icon (it should be named like your project, "Journey" ?). In the middle, select the *"Summary"* tab and make sure in the *"Main Interface"* textfield you have *"MainWindow"*.

Comment: there is nothing like In my Xcode menu, select View -> Navigators -> Project .

Comment: Then you must still be using Xcode3. I don't know any more where it it there. You can look into you *"Info.plist"* file. Just search your project for *"uMainWindow"* and replace it with *"MainWindow"*, I'm afraid I can't help you any further.

Comment: Thank you very much It help me more

Comment: IT work But I don't how it get change Is that any idea >How it get change

Answer (score 0):

As the errors says it doesn't seem to find your nib file.

Try and load your .xib file in the controller initialization

`YourController *controller = [[YourController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NameOfYourNibFile" bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle];`

Answer (score 0):

run "clean" on you project, and see if the problem persists. By the way u changed the name of the standard MainWindow to uMainWindow, just checking if you did it on purpose.

Comment: nt retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil); it get crash with Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/HarishYadav/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/A6DC7F9F-F271-4DA8-B937-B05CA42EDA84/Journey.app> (loaded)' with name 'uMainWindow'' *** Call stack at first throw:

Answer (score 0):

Your XIB file should have at least an "App Delegate" and a "Window".
Check the following things:

- Open the Identity Inspector for the "App Delegate" and check the class, it should be the name of your AppDelegate class as you called in XCode.
- Open the Connections inspector for the "App Delegate" and check that the Referencing outlet "delegate" points to "File's Owner"
- Open the Connections inspector for the "Window" and check that the Referencing outlet "window" points to "App Delegate"

Comment: int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil); it get crash with Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/HarishYadav/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/A6DC7F9F-F271-4DA8-B937-B05CA42EDA84/Journey.app> (loaded)' with name 'uMainWindow''
*** Call stack at first throw:

Answer (score 0):

This type of crashing happens when you are using your database file into many methods and you are opening database many times. That time application did not release the memory and memory gets overloaded.
Simply dealloc your instance variable and open database one time when applcation running.
And application unable to load your xib file. This happens when you run your application more than 2 times continuously.